# SimpleGeo DotnetOpenAuth for C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, dotnetopenauth

I have moved simpleGeo sample from VB(langsamu) to C#. This is an amazing feature for my needs but i not abled to fix the OAuth class that i can't initialize correctly to test-it. I haved posted my complete project in this bottom link including sample. The simpleGeo.dll implement base classes to connect and query simpleGeo. Client.cs is the main point to go & implementing ConsumerBase. need and Gmaps key and simpleGeo key easier to get. Can someone help me to fix.

Thanks for your help, Romi.

here VB : http github.com / simplegeo / simplegeo-dotnet

here C# : [C# simpleGeo that need your help](http://help.simplegeo.com/entries/227872-simplegeo-for-c)

```
namespace SimpleGeo
{
    public class Client : DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ConsumerBase
    {
        private SimpleGeo.Description Services;
        private SimpleGeo.TokenManager Tokens;

        public Client(Version Version, string Key, string Secret): base(new Description(Version), new TokenManager(Key, Secret))
        {
            //added because not firing Public proprieties of base.
            Services = new Description(Version);//remplace Services
            Tokens = new TokenManager(Key, Secret);//remplace Token
        }
        ...
        public ServiceProviderDescription Service
        {
            get { return base.ServiceProvider; }
        }

        private IConsumerTokenManager Token
        {
            get { return base.TokenManager; }
        } 
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I love simplegeo but the guys dont see .NET as a viable API consumer :) - VB sample is pretty much useless and [SimpleGeo.NET](https://github.com/jbattermann/SimpleGeo.Net) seems abandoned (?). I decided to roll out my own client for a project I have in mind and since there is an excellent REST library supporting OAuth ([RestSharp](https://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp)) I gave it a try with simplegeo. A very rude example follows:

```
//create client and pass OAuth credentials
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://api.simplegeo.com");
client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(yourapikey, yoursecret);

//sample of creating a request for a specific simplegeo endpoint (places near an IP)
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET) {Resource = "{version}/places/{ip}.json", RequestFormat.Json};
request.AddParameter("version", "1.0", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("ip", anyiphere, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

//call the api function 
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

//get the simplegeo response in json
string json = response.Content;
```

Use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) for deserializing into any custom classes of yours.

You may have a helper class constructing the request for you according to parameters passed - keep *version* somewhere not hardcoded just in case :)